# Hide Crystal Report Header

Tags: crystal-reports

In my Crystal Report have a Page Header(section Page Header "a" and Page Header "b") and Groupe Header #1 and #2

My problem is, I want to hide Page Header "a" when Group #2 have more records, I want to print records next page without Page Header "a".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide Crystal Report Header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047813/hide-crystal-report-header)

Answer (score 0):

This could be tricky business depending on which version of Crystal you are using, because you are asking the reporting engine to report on a count of a grouped records that could potentially span across multiple pages.  Without knowing much else about your system, the following *might* work.

Implement two running total fields that count records returned, one for Group #1 and the other for Group#2.  Each running total should count records returned in each group, resetting on a of group.  Then you would put the following in your suppression formula for `Page Header a`:

```
// The following line will suppress the header when
// Group2RecordCount is greater than Group1RecordCount

{#Group2RecordCount} > {#Group1RecordCount};
```